# Running script to replace "null" with nothing in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-addons

I tried to do this through a macro but I'm unable to have it actually record. I'm not a coder so I've been recording macros and using the code from there to create an add on. I need a script that can find "null" and replace it with nothing. Not null as in no value, I mean the sheets are literally showing null as a value. I'd use Ctrl+H to find and replace but I need to do this for 50 or so reports on a regular basis.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that using the macro recorder to copy code automatically generated will be enough to create a G Suite Document Editor add-on, but you have to start somewhere.

Google Apps Script is based on JavaScript so you can use the JavaScript comparison operators and as well the String methods including regular expressions. By the other hand, the Google Apps Script Spreadsheet Servics has [Class TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder) that could make the things easier.

I didn't used Class TextFinder yet but it looks promising.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to make it work with one code on Google Sheets by turning it into an add-on so I know it can work, I just need to figure out the code for it. I'll check out Class TextFinder and see if it can help me make the code for it. I'm trying to learn Script code but haven't had the time to really get into it yet.